# Navigate stop only when going to another website

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html

I am using following code to trigger the are you sure leaving website alert but for some reason its not recognising my if else condition in it and only works if I only put `return true` in  `window.onbeforeunload = function() { return true }` . Is there a way I can trigger this alert only when user is navigating away from my website cause at the moment without if else condition its asking if user tries to navigate in the same website as well?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
 var location = window.document.activeElement.href;
if (typeof location != 'undefined')
{
 console.log(location);
} else { reutn true; }

};
```

Comment: You can't prevent user from proceeding where they want to, all you can do is ask them if they want to. Providing a poor user experience is a sure way to make them not want to stay or come back

Comment: @charlietfl I don't want to prevent them. Basically all I want to do is when they are navigating on my website then leaving website alert shouldn't come in but when they are navigating away then only in that case the alert should come in whether they want to stay or leave. So is there a way of  doing that or is it not possible to do at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag and toggle that flagged based on `host` of links that are clicked

```
var host = location.hostname,
   allowNavigate = false;

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if (!allowNavigate) {
    return 'Message string';// not what actually gets displayed in most browsers these days
  }
  //don't return anything
  return;
};

window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(a) {
    a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      allowNavigate = this.hostname === host;
    });
  });
};
```

The `hostname` on this page for example is `"stackoverflow.com"`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/HY7pswaRB3J6bJGA3Hm8?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks but this solution will not work in case user opens a url from bookmark bar or manually enters a url in the browser url field. I tested it and its not working.

Comment: and I get this issue in console when I try to do this by if else using my above code: http://prntscr.com/h9hmmw

Comment: That whole event has been so abused over the years and has become a lot more restrictive than it used to be

Answer (score 0):

You can add the "window.onbeforeunload"  dynamically for the links you want to see the prompt message

and remove the "window.onbeforeunload" for the links you don't want prompt

```
<a onClick="a(true)" href="https://www.w3schools.com">Click here to get promt before navigate</a>
<br>
<a onClick="a(false)" href="https://jsfiddle.net/">Click here to navigate without promt </a>

<script>
function a(showPrompt){
    window.onbeforeunload =  showPrompt ? function(e) {return '';}: null;
}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vqsnmamy/1/